# Cannot find Kotlin class using Java instantiation

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this Kotlin class:

```kotlin
package com.example.project

class BasketAdapter(val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
    ...
}
```

When I try to instantiate from my Java code, I always get *"error: cannot find symbol"*. This is how I try to instantiate the class in Java:

```java
package com.example.project
...
public class BasketFragment extends Fragment {
...
    BasketAdapter adapter = new BasketAdapter(requireContext());
    binding.listviewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
...
}
```

Can someone explain the issue?

Comment: I have code just like yours and it works. The issue must be elsewhere. Try to replicate the issue in a new project.

Comment: I tried to write the adapter in java and the instantiation works. Then tried the "Convert Java File to Kotlin File", the generated kotlin file issues the same error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the **exact** and **complete** error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any resolution. I ended up converting my Adapter class to Java code.